# How to auto-uppercase MySQL after typing keywords?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I type pretty fast so I want MySQL Workbench to auto-capitalize keywords after I type them. I've seen a solution to a similar question which is MySQLWorkbench-> Preferences-> Query Editor-> Change keywords to UPPER CASE. However this only provides uppercase for autofill. The problem is that the dropdown menu takes a second to load and hinders my work flow.

Is there any solution to this problem? Could I create a trigger for this or is that not helpful?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because It's a querying language whereas what you ask is about a software, which happens to support that language. You're not entirely far-off but I think there's a distinction still.

Comment: I'd rebuttal saying that a trigger is a set of statements in the MySQL catalog which is activated by a DML statement. Seeing that it is a possible solution, I do think that this should have the mysql tag.

Comment: Why would you think you could do this in a trigger? A trigger executes when data is inserted, updated or deleted. It has no knowledge of the SQL that you've typed or what case that SQL is written in - it simply knows that it's supposed to do something when one of the operations I've mentioned is done. What you're asking is strictly related to what you're seeing in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: I didn't know that it only effected the real data. Looks like it's pretty useful for changing to uppercase in the tables then. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Not an automatic solution but something useful: look in the Edit -> Format menu. It has entries to upcase + downcase keywords, as well as other formatting commands.